# How can I make a secondary NIC port "eth0"?

Tags: linux, networking, centos, ethernet

I am using `CentOS 5.9`. One of my servers recently had a malfunctioning NIC port.  The software running on the server was hard-coded to use `eth0`.  The other physical NIC ports were fine and unused. The issue is now resolved but I'm curious, how hard would it be to convince CentOS that the other NIC port is `eth0`?

Is it just a matter of editing `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` and setting `HWADDR=<MAC Address of second NIC port>` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adjusting

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 (HWADDR)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: The udev rules bit is applicable to most modern Linux distros.

Comment: persistent-net.rules name could be different depending on OS. For example for for suse it could be 30-net_persistent_names.rules.

Comment: Just for grins, I checked this on a VM and I don't see `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`.  Is this file only present on bare-metal systems?

Answer (score 1):

Open `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` with your favorite editor and Do below changes

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:50:56:xx:xx:xx", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"
```

then

```
cd /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/
```

put the HWADDR entry in ifcfg-eth1 file

```
 DEVICE="eth1"
 BOOTPROTO="static"
 HWADDR="00:50:56:xx:xx:xx"
 IPADDR="192.168.x.x"
 NETMASK="255.255.255.0"
 ONBOOT="yes"
```

then after rebooting your system & you will be able to get IP assign in ifcfg-eth1